# Decoupling business logic from API - how to decouple helper classes

Tags: c#, api, .net-core

All methods in my business logic return the same class type. That class has 3 properties: a success\fail boolean, and 2 dynamic properties(1 for fail result and 1 for success result). How can I decouple this business logic, if both my main API and the business logic need to know about this custom class?

Comment: Normally a "cross cutting concerns" (or simpler "core") project is created so that you can put common logic/models there and use it across projects

Comment: Got it. Thank you!